# How do I Parse an AST in Python to Find Just the Variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm looking to build an extremely restricted lambda processor submitted by users. I'm using the following code to do so:

```
import ast, operator
from math import *

#make a list of safe functions
safe_list = ["math", "lambda"]

# use the list to filter the local namespace
safe_dict = dict([(k, locals().get(k, None)) for k in safe_list])

all_args = []
user_submitted_fxn_example = "d>15"
node = ast.parse(user_submitted_fxn_example, mode="eval")
for elem in ast.walk(node):
  if isinstance(elem, ast.Name):
    all_args.append(str(elem.id))

lambda_string = f"lambda {','.join(all_args)}: {fxn}"
a = eval(f"lambda {','.join(all_args)}: {fxn}", {"__builtins__": None}, safe_dict)
print(a(11)) # => Correctly reports 'False'
```

According to [this](https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nodes.html#variables), the right way to build the list of variables to put in the lambad is with ast.Name but when I do the following, I get both `sin` and `x` as a Name.

```
user_submitted_fxn_example = "sin(d)>0.5"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Functions are held in variables like any other. You're going to need to decide on your own separation criteria, if you want to separate them.

Comment: From a Python syntactical perspective, the `sin` and the `d` in that expression are the exact same kind of thing.

Comment: oh interesting - is there some attribute on the node I can investigate to figure out if it's a function or not? happy to reject anything that's not a built-in function

Answer (score 1):

`ast.Call` nodes represent function calls. They have 2 key attributes: `func` and `args`. The `ast.Name` node in `func` represents the method name. `args` is a list of ast nodes. You might want to do a depth-first search for each node in `args`, and then look for `ast.Name` nodes. The reason for doing a DFS is that you could have an input like `sin(f(x))`, where `f(x)` would be yet another `ast.Call` node which contains `ast.Name` in the `args` field.

I recommend that you play around with some examples [here](https://python-ast-explorer.com/).